# How to identify whether a cell has a specific numeric value using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to find whether a cell has the particular value "0.0".  However, I didn't realize that in the event 10.0 was a value, the program would pick it up as well.  How do I modify the code to pick up exactly only 0.0?

```
Sub ReformatDeplete()

Dim SrchRng3 As Range
Dim c3 As Range, f As String

Set SrchRng3 = Worksheets("Melanoma").Range("M4", Worksheets("Melanoma").Range("M65536").End(xlUp))
Set c3 = SrchRng3.Find("0.0", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c3 Is Nothing Then
    f = c3.Address
    Do
        With Worksheets("Melanoma").Range("A" & c3.Row & ":M" & c3.Row)
            .Font.ColorIndex = 1
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 16
        End With
        Set c3 = SrchRng3.FindNext(c3)
    Loop While c3.Address <> f
End If

End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `Lookat` argument of the `.Find` function.

```
Set c3 = SrchRng3.Find("0.0", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
```

There are two constants for this argument, `xlPart` and `xlWhole`. As you've noticed, if left unspecified, the function defaults to `xlPart`.

To learn more about the `.Find` function, [check out this link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!